# Get newly created process id via command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

If i start a new process using command line in Batch file.
How can i get newly created process id.

// In Batch file

C:\users\prashant>notepad

Here I have opened a new Notepad process, How can i get a Notepad process id

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==;" %A in ('wmic process call create notepad ^| findstr /i /c:processid') do set pid=%A
set pid=%pid:~1,4%
```

This starts program using WMIC which returns a PID. Findstr removes extra lines and the second line handle WMIC's uniciode.

Answer (score 0):

You could start the batch file upfront, continously dumping the tasklist to a text file only retrieving the first to columns (memory size probaly continously changes) and write it into tasks_now.txt

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=, skip=1" %%f IN ('tasklist /FO:CSV') DO ( echo %%f %%g >> tasks_now.txt )
```

Then you can compare tasks_now.txt to the tasklist before by using the file compare command:

```
fc tasks_now.txt tasks_earlier.txt > diff.txt
```

If `%errorlevel%` is 0 then no differences occured and no new processes were created. Now you copy _now to _earlier for the next round.

Else you can run FIND on diff.txt in order to find the new process. If a task by the same name already existed before it might be required to check in tasks_earlier.txt, if it was there already (again with FIND) - if not, then you have your new task.

Comment: Brittle. This isn't going to distinguish between the process launched from the batch script, and launched by the user or the system. And sampling will miss anything that happens in between arbitrarily chosen sampling points.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `wmic` to create the process and get its process ID in one operation.

The basic principle is:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=;= " %%A IN (`wmic process call create '"notepad","%cd%",null'  ^|find "ProcessId"`)  do set /A PID=%%A
```

`notepad` is the command line to run, and `%cd%` is the working directory (in this case, the current one).

Afterwards, you should have the PID in `%PID%`.

However, there are some quoting issues with more complex command lines and parameters. There is a more complex but robust script doing exactly that, which I found here: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?pid=5876#p5876

The code, credits to user `smerch` on ss64.org:

> ```
> @echo off
> setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
>
> if "%~1" NEQ "" (
>   if "%~1" NEQ "-help" (
>       call :proc %*
>       exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
>   )
> )
>
> call :echoHelp
> exit /b
>
> :proc
>   call :argParser %*
>
>   if "%exec%" EQU "" (
>       call :err 1000
>       exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
>   )
>
>   if "%host%" NEQ "" (
>       set host=/NODE:%host%
>       if "%user%" NEQ "" (
>           set user=/USER:%user%
>           if "%pass%" NEQ "" (
>               set pass=/PASSWORD:%pass%
>           )
>       )
>   )
>
>   if "%record%" NEQ "" (
>       set record=/RECORD:%record%
>   )
>
>   set global_params=%record% %host% %user% %pass%
>
>   for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%G IN (`wmic  %global_params%  process call create "%exec% %commandline%"^,"%workdir%"`) do ( 
>       rem echo %%G
>       set _tmp=%%G
>       set _tmp=!_tmp:^>=^^^>!
>       echo !_tmp! | find "ProcessId" > nul && (
>           for /f  "tokens=2 delims=;= " %%H in ('echo !_tmp!') do (
>               call set /A PID=%%H
>           )
>       )
>       echo !_tmp! | find "ReturnValue" > nul && (
>           for /f  "tokens=2 delims=;= " %%I in ('echo !_tmp!') do (
>               call set /A RETCOD=%%I
>           )
>       )
>       call :concat
>   )
>   set _tmp=
>
>   rem successful execution
>   if "%PID%" NEQ "" (
>       echo %PID%
>       exit /b
>       rem exit /B %PID%
>   ) else (
>       call :err %RETCOD%
>   )
> exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
>
>
> :concat
>
>   call set output=%output% ^& echo !_tmp:^>=^^^>!
> exit /b
>
> :argParser
>
>   set comstr=-exec-commandline-workdir-host-user-pass-record
>   :nextShift
>   set /A shifter=shifter+1
>   echo %comstr% | find "%~1" > nul && (
>       set _tmp=%~1
>       set !_tmp:-=!=%~2
>   )
>   shift & shift
>   if %shifter% LSS 7 goto :nextShift
>   set _tmp=
>   set shifter=
> exit /b
>
> :echoHelp
>
>   echo %~n0 -exec executubale {-commandline command_line} { -workdir working_directory} 
>   echo  {-host  remote_host {-user user {-pass password}}} {-record path_to_xml_output}
>   echo\
>   echo localhost cant' be used as in -host variable
>   echo Examples:
>   echo %~n0  -exec "notepad" -workdir "c:/"  -record "test.xml" -commandline "/A startpid.txt"
>   echo %~n0  -exec "cmd" -workdir "c:/"  -record "test.xml" -host remoteHost -user User
> exit /b
>
> :err
>   if %1 EQU 2          (set errmsg=Access Denied)
>   if %1 EQU 3          (set errmsg=Insufficient Privilege)
>   if %1 EQU 8          (set errmsg=Unknown failure ^& echo Hint: Check if the executable and workdit exists or if command line parameters are correct.)
>   if %1 EQU 9          (set errmsg=Path Not Found ^& echo Hint: check if the workdir exists on the remote machine.)
>   if %1 EQU 21         (set errmsg=Invalid Parameter ^& echo Hint: Check executable path. Check if host and user are corect.)
>   if %1 EQU 1000       (set errmsg=Executable not defined.)
>   if "%errmsg:~0,1%" EQU "" (set errmsg=%output% ^& echo Hint: brackets, quotes or commas in the password may could breack the script.)
>
>   echo %errmsg%
> exit /b %1
> ```